# Regex to exclude specific special characters, spaces and alphabets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want a regular expression which converts this:

```
91009-01-28-00 Maximum (c/s)................  1543.5
```

to this:

```
91009-01-28-00    1543.5
```

So basically, a regular expression that escapes alphabets, spaces, forward slashes and brackets.

I have written the following python code so far:

```
with open('lcstats.txt', 'r') as lcstats_file:
        with open (lcstats_full_path + '_lcstats_full.txt', "a+") as lcstats_full_file:
            lcstats_full_file.write(obsid )
            for line in lcstats_file.readlines():
                if not re.search(r'Maximum [(c/s)]', line):
                    continue
                line = (re.sub(**REGEX**,'',line))  
                lcstats_full_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Your expected output implies, at least to me, that you want to remove every characters which is not a digit, a dot (when appearing inside a number), or a hyphen.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes and a space too.

Comment: The `(` and `)` should have been escaped, not placed inside `[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using search to check if you can match `Maximum (c/s)` and then you want to use a regex to remove that.

I think with your regex `Maximum [(c/s)]` you mean `Maximum \(c/s\)`. The square brackets make it a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and `(c/s)` captures `c/s` in a capturing group which is not required if you only want to match it.

Wat you could do is match `Maximum (c/s)` and match one or more times a whitespace or a comma using a character class `[ .]+` and replace with an empty string.

[`Maximum \(c/s\)[ .]+`](https://regex101.com/r/OGJCTc/1)

```
import re

s = "91009-01-28-00 Maximum (c/s)................  1543.5"
print( re.sub(r"Maximum \(c/s\)[ .]+", "", s))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KZTQP97091)

Comment: This just removes the . (fullstops). I want to remove 'Maximum (c/s)' too.

Comment: @NealTitusThomas I have updated my answer and removed the capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want to have first and last part of the string. If that is the case for every line than spliting it accordingly can be helpful, as in the following code

```
import re
line = "91009-01-28-00 Maximum (c/s) ................  1543.5"
line=line.split(' ')
line=line[0]+' '+ line[-1]
print(line)
```

Output:

```
91009-01-28-00 1543.5
```

Comment: I want to do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex `/\s[^0-9]+/` This will match from the first space followed by 1 or more not digit characters. You will need to add a space in the replacement string to keep the two bits of remaining data separate.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
((?<!\d)\D)
```

Match  all non digits`\D` which is not followed by a digit `\d`

Comment: This converts 91009-01-28-00 Maximum (c/s)................  1543.5 to 91009-01-28-00Maximu(c/s1543.5